# How do I create an object after it has been disposed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I dispose a object in my code and I want to now create it again.

How can I do this?

Answer is :

```
private void showToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xpPanelGroup1.CreateControl();
        xpPanelGroup1.Visible = true;
         ...


    }
    private void noShowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                xpPanelGroup1.Visible = false;
                  ...
                xpPanelGroup1.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Could you add your code please?

Comment: No no no no no no no - calling CreateControl() might recreate an underlying windows handle, but the actual Control itself has still been disposed. You'll find that when you do eventually close the form, the new control handle is never cleaned up. You're heading in exactly the right direction to experience a host of debugging pain later in your project - and for your application to introduce instability on your users machines.

Comment: hey man,i have to dispose my control.so,all answer that use .Visible = true     not work for me!
OK?
so,dont push negative Vote on my Question  X<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new object after you have called `Dispose()`.

But if you want to reuse the object later you should not dispose it, you may try to use `Hide` or `.Visible = false` or similar if you temporarily want to hide a control.

**Edit:** In your code you create a new xpPanelGroup1:

```
UIComponents.XPPanelGroup xpPanelGroup1 = new UIComponents.XPPanelGroup() ;
```

but that is only local to the `showToolStripMenuItem_Click` method. If you just type

```
xpPanelGroup1 = new UIComponents.XPPanelGroup() ;
```

you are using the class member, that is the same variable you dispose in the noShow method.
But I still recommend just hiding instead of disposing.

Comment: +1 on using Hide() or Visible = false or similar. Why? Before calling Dispose() on any WinForms control, you need to make sure you properly remove it from the form - take it out of the relevant Controls list, unhook any events, etc. It can be done - but it's pretty complex to get right, and very easy to end up with a nasty memory leak, or worse.

Comment: please say another way...
i dispose it :|

Comment: Just don't dispose it.  It gets automatically disposed when the form closes.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look in your design code (the ".designer.cs" file automatically generated by at design time), and try to call it. This is the code run when the widget is instantiated.

Comment: But the code generated by the WinForms designer is only designed to be run *once* per instance. Running it multiple times for a single instance will leak lots of USER handles. Run out of those (the limit per process is just 10k) and your process will be killed outright, like a soap bubble bursting. No Dr Watson, no logging, nothing - just *gone*. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just set the object to null instead of disposing it and reassign it to another value when you want to use it again.

Comment: Problem is that WinForms controls tend to grab references to each other, often behind the scenes.